HttpClient Timeout on Live Server for Paginated API Requests
I am working on an ASP.NET  application where I fetch paginated product data from an external API. The code executes fine on the first page, but when fetching page 2 on the live server, the process consistently fails with a TaskCanceledException due to an HttpClient.Timeout elapsing. Interestingly, this issue doesn’t occur when running the same code locally.
public async Task GetLastChangeProductsAsync(IFormCollection formCollection = default)
{
    await FillProductCharacteristicsAsync(); // Load product characteristics
    int pageNumber = 1;
    
    // Load last change data from a file
    string lastChangeData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(lastChangeDataPath);
    var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(lastChangeData);
    JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(lastChangeData);
    string date = value.LastChangeData;

    if (formCollection != default)
    {
        pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(formCollection["page"]);
    }

    // Loop through product pages
    while (areProducts)
    {
        await _logger.LoggerAsync(pageNumber.ToString(), "Products Page Number", "TextLogger");
        
        // Fetch products for the current page
        var x = await _productsListService.GetLastChangeProducts(date, pageNumber, 100);
        if (!x.Product.Any())
        {
            areProducts = false;
        }
        pageNumber++; // Increment page number for the next iteration
    }

    // Update last sync date
    string lastSyncDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");
    jsonObj["LastChangeData"] = lastSyncDate;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(lastChangeDataPath, jsonObj.ToString());

    // Execute a stored procedure after synchronization
    try
    {
        await _logger.LoggerAsync(pageNumber.ToString(), "Procedure executing...", "TextLogger");
        await _dataProvider.ExecuteNonQueryAsync("[dbo].[AfterSync]");
        await _logger.LoggerAsync(pageNumber.ToString(), "Done...", "TextLogger");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _logger.LoggerAsync(ex.ToString(), "Error while Procedure executing", "ProcedureError");
    }
}


Increasing Timeout: I have increased the HttpClient.Timeout to 100 seconds, but the issue persists on page 2.
Reducing Page Size: I tried reducing the number of items per page from 100 to 50, but this didn’t resolve the issue either.
In my logs, I can see that the process stops when trying to fetch page 2, and the logs for "Procedure executing..." and "Done..." are missing. The request on page 2 throws the following error:
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.


If you use something like Postman to simulate the request, does the server respond in a timely manner for page 2?
